# Is there a way to sort few numbers that consider more numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for a algorithm to sort some numbers. The input is like 300 lines of 3 number parts and I want to have max values of numbers in first, second and third positions.

Example input:

F S T

1 2 3

1 1 1

1 0 0

1 1 0

2 1 0

and output:

2 1 0

1 2 3

1 1 1

1 1 0

1 0 0

Comment: Is the idea to treat each trio of numerals as a 3-digit number and sort those?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've asked for an algorithm, any [comparison-based sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) will do: you could use quicksort, or merge sort, or heap sort, for example.

The trick is that you are sorting rows, so you need to define how to "compare" one row with another. For your purpose, row A is "less than or equal to" row B if either

- `A[0] < B[0]`, or
- `A[0] == B[0]` and either

  - `A[1] < B[1]`, or
  - `A[1] == B[1]` and `A[2] <= B[2]`

To actually implement the algorithm, all you need to do is take an implementation of your preferred comparison-based sorting algorithm, and replace the part which does a `<=` comparison on two elements with the appropriate logic to do the comparison on rows described above.

Comment: And which algorithm comparison-based in your opinion will be the fastest one for 300 rows.

Comment: All of them will be plenty fast for only 300 rows. If you are implementing this in an actual program, you should consider using a sort function from your programming language's standard library instead of implementing your own.